# How to adjust script to choose uncalled leads first

Tags: php, mysql

I have very basic PHP knowledge, and have been given this system to modify.

There is a table which has propestive customers in that sales staff can call. At the moment it start at the beginning of the table and works its way down as it would normally in Mysql.

I want it to call all new records first then go through the older ones.

I have tried using ORDER BY lead_id DESC but that doesnt seem to work, and also lead_callcount ASC but again that doesnt work.

I have been looking at the CASE option but do not know enough to use it myself.

The code is currently

```
public static function getNextLead(){

    $lead_res = Database::get()->data->query("SELECT `lead_id` FROM `" . DATABASE_TBL_LEADS . "` WHERE (`lead_disposition` IS NULL OR `lead_disposition` = 1) AND (`lead_timeout` IS NULL OR `lead_timeout` < NOW()) AND (`lead_locked` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR `lead_locked` IS NULL) AND `lead_active` = '1' LIMIT 1");
    $lead_num = $lead_res->numRows();

    if($lead_num == 1){

        $lead_get = $lead_res->fetchRow(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

        $lead_id = $lead_get['lead_id'];
```

There is more code below that,

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the available columns in the Database TABLE you are working with; it's hard to say for sure.  I would suggest you:

1. Obtain the table SCHEMA if you do not already have it
2. See if there is a column for the date that the lead was added
3. If so; ORDER BY that column

**Since we have the table schema to look at:**
ORDER BY can sort a result set by either ASC or DESC; the default value is ASC (starting at the lowest and working up from there).

Presumably ASC order should work for you for callcount; but maybe you could add lead_timeout if that is a relevant value - is that time since last call maybe?

If so something like this might help:

```
ORDER BY `lead_callcount` ASC,
         `lead_timeout` ASC
```

You could optionally change the lead_timeout to DESC if it would be better to have a longer (rather than shorter timeout)

I created a test table in my local database and tried out the query you provided with an ORDER BY keyed off of the lead_callcount and it seemed to work okay.

*For purposes of checking things like basic syntax and query structure; your above query would look like this with the ORDER BY added:*

```
SELECT lead_id, lead_callcount, lead_timeout FROM `leads` 
WHERE (`lead_disposition` IS NULL OR `lead_disposition` = 1) 
  AND (`lead_timeout` IS NULL OR `lead_timeout` < NOW()) 
  AND (`lead_locked` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR `lead_locked` IS NULL) 
  AND `lead_active` = '1'
ORDER BY `lead_callcount` ASC
        #,`lead_timeout` ASC #optional sort by lead_timeout
```

Comment: There is no date when the lead was added, The callcount will be 0 once added, when the lead has been called once it becomes 1 etc. WHich is why i tried to use that column. For some reason the ORDER BY doesnt seem to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is the list of columns:

lead_id
lead_ref
lead_title
lead_fname
lead_sname
lead_phone
lead_addr1
lead_addr2
lead_addr3
lead_addr4
lead_addr5
lead_addr6
lead_disposition
lead_timeout
lead_callcount
lead_locked
lead_active

Comment: I've updated my answer; as I mentioned above I created a test version of the leads table on my local DEV and fiddled with the query a bit.  That seemed to work for me but then I am not working with it under a heavy load/production environment.